# Semantic UI React progress bar with file upload

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I have a small file upload component where the user picks a file from their file system and uploads it (sent via REST call).

I'm trying to implement [`<Progress>`](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/progress/) module from semantic-ui-react to indicate success/failure when the file is sent to the endpoint. So is it best to do this based off the `status` of the response? Or is there a better way to handle it?

Codesandbox is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/5wxr0mwq5p)

```
    class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          file: null,
          fileName: "",
          isUploading: false,
          statusCode: ""
        };
      }

      onFormSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault(); // Stop form submit
        this.fileUpload(this.state.file).then(response => {
          console.log(response.data);
        });
      };

      fileChange = e => {
        this.setState(
          { file: e.target.files[0], fileName: e.target.files[0].name },
          () => {
            console.log(
              "File chosen --->",
              this.state.file,
              console.log("File name  --->", this.state.fileName)
            );
          }
        );
      };


  fileUpload = async file => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);
    try {
      axios.post("/file/upload/enpoint").then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        console.log(response.status);
        this.setState({ statusCode: response.status }, () => {
          console.log(
            "This is the response status code --->",
            this.state.statusCode
          );
        });
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(Error(`Error uploading file ${error.message}`));
    }

    const data = JSON.stringify({
      uploadData: file
    });
    console.log(data);
  };

  render() {
    const { statusCode } = this.state;
    const panes = [
      {
        menuItem: "Import ",
        render: () => (
          <Tab.Pane attached={false}>
            <Message>Some random message idk.</Message>
            <Form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
              <Form.Field>
                <label>File input & upload </label>
                <Button as="label" htmlFor="file" type="button" animated="fade">
                  <Button.Content visible>
                    <Icon name="file" />
                  </Button.Content>
                  <Button.Content hidden>Choose a File</Button.Content>
                </Button>
                <input
                  type="file"
                  id="file"
                  hidden
                  onChange={this.fileChange}
                />
                <Form.Input
                  fluid
                  label="File Chosen: "
                  placeholder="Use the above bar to browse your file system"
                  readOnly
                  value={this.state.fileName}
                />
                <Button style={{ marginTop: "20px" }} type="submit">
                  Upload
                </Button>
                {statusCode && statusCode === "200" ? (
                  <Progress
                    style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}
                    percent={100}
                    success
                    active
                    progress
                  />
                ) : statusCode && statusCode === "500" ? (
                  <Progress
                    style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}
                    percent={100}
                    error
                    active
                    progress
                  />
                ) : null}
              </Form.Field>
                </Form>
              </Tab.Pane>
            )
          }
        ];
        return (
          <Segment style={{ padding: "5em 1em" }} vertical>
            <Divider horizontal>OFFLINE USAGE</Divider>
            <Tab menu={{ pointing: true }} panes={panes} />
          </Segment>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Do you use redux? Because there is a better way to show an indicator using reducers.

Comment: I do not, I kinda don't want to introduce Redux for a such a small feature. But depending on how simple it is, I'd consider. Ideally, I just want to show a full bar showing success or failure based on the `response.stats` codes

Comment: @DushanRandika do you have a link or a proposed solution using redux? I'd be interested in taking a look

Comment: I had a proposed solution. But I had to do a couple of changes for that. However, I'll make a solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have a proposed solution that is mainly focused on the reducers. What you have to do is you have to dispatch a loading action.

Go to my Github repo: [Semantic UI Indicator](https://github.com/dushanrandika/Semantic-UI-Loading-Indicator)

You would be able to go through the repo and understand that. This is just a different method. So there can be many ways to do that. I have used a simple semantic loader in case you can apply the same thing to the progress bar.

Comment: I've decided to conditionally render a 0 or 100% percent progress bar indicator based on the status code form the server response. It seems overkill to implement redux for such a simple feature. But thank you for your solution, I may decide later on to implement this if I use Redux for something else.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the `fileUpload` function to update a `statusCode` state variable with the `response.status` from the server response.

```
  fileUpload = async file => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);
    try {
      axios.post("/file/upload/enpoint").then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        console.log(response.status);
        this.setState({ statusCode: response.status }, () => {
          console.log(
            "This is the response status code --->",
            this.state.statusCode
          );
        });
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(Error(`Error uploading file ${error.message}`));
    }
  };
```

Then in render I checked for the `statusCode` to be either `200` or `500`, I will change it to include more appropriate status codes but you get the idea.

```
{statusCode && statusCode === 200 ? (
                  <Progress
                    style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}
                    percent={100}
                    success
                    progress
                  >
                    File Upload Success
                  </Progress>
                ) : statusCode && statusCode === 500 ? (
                  <Progress
                    style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}
                    percent={100}
                    error
                    active
                    progress
                  >
                    File Upload Failed
                  </Progress>
                ) : null}
```

The updated codesandbox can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/5wxr0mwq5p) for those who want to take a look.